# checksum detection of changes

Tags: java, c++, checksum

I'm trying to figure out an easy way to use checksums to check if an executable has been tampered with.

I know that checksums are not foolproof.
I am also not looking for a solution that would be needed against a dedicated (malicious) adversary.

My situation is: in an environment where "Wild West" coding idioms take place  people feel free to modify / recompile things that are supposedly "releases".  I want to be able to tell if what I call release X is the same as when it was made.  That way if something "mysteriously" breaks I can either point to bad sofware practices, or definatively rule them out and concentrate on bugs.

I know that a checksum should detect alterations in the code that was compiled.  What I don't know is if it will detect that something the code depends on (like a library) has been changed....

I'm mainly dealing with C++ code but there's some Java code too.  Will checksums detect not only alterations to the code but also what the code depends on?  If not is there a good relatively easy solution for doing so?

Comment: I've noticed that Java class checksums differ from compile to compile, even for the exact same source code. I believe this is due to timestamps or some other metadata stored in the class that changes with each compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A checksum will definitely let you know if a change was made to a file, but it can only tell you about changes to the files you run a checksum against.  You can maintain a list of files and their original checksum and then write a script to compare the checksums of each.  You might also modify your build scripts to update the version (build count) on every build - possibly also recording the user name of the person running the build - and introduce a version function in your executables to display that info for itself and it's libraries.

Good luck fighting the natives!

Comment: The "natives" are always the good guys.  It is the cocksure cowboys who feel altering code, or switching underlying libraries (without even letting anyone know) is just fine.  And just like then they have the guns and the power (at least here).  If I can implement this checksum thing I may be able to force some decent policies though.

Comment: "write a script to compare the checksums of each" or you could use one of the gnu checksum programs. `sha256sum --check checksums.txt` for instance. https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sha2-utilities.html.

Answer (score 0):

A checksum will only include the things you take the checksum of. So you have to hunt down the dependencies, or modifications thereof will not be detected. As far as I know, there is no easy solution to this problem.